# Can I use a satellite phone for 2 factor auth sms and such?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, phone, sms, satellite

Would 2 factor authentication SMS messages or other kinds of internet security notifications work with satellite phones? E.g. companies like Google, Paypal, Facebook, banking institutions and others would still send/recognize phone numbers associated with satellite carriers? Any experience?

Comment: Originally posted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1028292/can-i-use-a-satellite-phone-for-2-factor-auth-sms-and-such)

Comment: I don't see why not, from a technical standpoint. Some sat phones have a second virtual terrestrial number with a local area code, but I don't know if they interoperate with SMS

Comment: I just had a thought, if you are somewhere which requires a sat phone, you are going to struggle with internet connectivity. Just curious as to the use case in this instance.

Comment: @Burgi the sat phone itself is the solution for very light Internet use.

Comment: What about using TOTP or HOTP which do not depend on any network connection and as a bonus are more secure since there is no middleman handling the OTP (as opposed to a phone where the carrier can intercept the OTP) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there should not be a technical problem using satellite phones for 2 factor auth, but there is a cost aspect for the service provider that might stop it. As the service provider normally pays for the texts used for 2 factor authentication, there may be limitations set up.

On [this site](https://www.multitel.net/docs/view/159/tutorials/) you will see how the supplier mentions the fact that satellite phones would be a huge expense for the business.

> Maximum call rate : Since you are paying for the outbound calls , you also have the option to limit the cost per minute associated with
>   these calls. You probably do not want your end-users authenticating
>   themselves using Satellite phones (that would be very expensive,
>   ouch!)